# Como retornar un include dentro de una funcion en PHP

Tags: php

Estimados tengo la siguiente duda, estoy retornando una funcion mediante php y ajax para poder visualizar los datos de una tabla en mysql. Por decirlo de algun modo en la tabla tengo almacenado el nombre del archivo a incluir en la funcion php. Mi idea es generar una pagina dinamica por cada registro en la tabla. No tengo ningun inconveniente con eso. Pero si con lo siguiente, mi idea es que el encabezado de cada pagina sea igual para todas, pero quiero que el cuerpo de la pagina sea diferente dependiendo de la pagina, para esto se me ocurre la idea de incluir un archivo con el cuerpo de cada pagina. No tengo ningun problema en mostrar el encabezado, pero si realizo el include al archivo, la funcion no muestra ningun dato.

Adjunto el codigo

```
<?php include '../logica/conexion.php';
class MostrarServicio {
    public function servicio(){
        $con = new Conexion();      
        $HTML = '';
        if(!(empty($_POST['clave']))){
            $clave = $_POST['clave'];
            $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE clave = '$clave'");
            if(count($datos) > 0){
                for($x=0;$x<count($datos);$x++){
                    $fila = $datos[$x];
                    $HTML .= '  <div class="container-fluid mb-4 background-top background" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.7),rgba(19,41,61,.7)),url(../'.$fila['ruta'].$fila['src'].')">
                                    <div class="titulo_pagina text-center text-white">
                                        <h1 class="display-3">'.$fila['titulo'].'</h1>
                                        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="../../" class="nav-link text-white p-0">HOME</a></li>
                                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="../" class="nav-link text-white p-0"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>SERVICIOS</a></li>
                                            <li class="nav-link text-muted p-0"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>'.$fila['titulo'].'</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                    $HTML .= '<div>'.include ('../include/solucion_dpf_egr.php').'</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    
        return $HTML;
    }           
}
$servicios = new MostrarServicio();
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    $html1 = $servicios->servicio();    
    $data = array(
        "html1" => $html1
    );
    echo json_encode($data);    
}
?>
```

Si quito esta parte del codigo la funcion se muestra correctamente

```
$HTML .= '<div>'.include ('../include/solucion_dpf_egr.php').'</div>';
```

El archivo a incluir es solo estrucutra HTML, como prodria lograr eso ?, estarioa agradecido de sus comentarios.

Comment: La pregunta está planteada de forma algo confusa. ¿Con esta parte del código: `$HTML .= '<div>'.include ('../include/solucion_dpf_egr.php').'</div>';` qué es lo que ocurre en sí? ¿No se muestra nada, da error, qué error? ¿Qué contiene `solucion_dpf_egr.php`? ¿Has hecho una prueba aislada de mostrar ese archivo solamente? Además, dado que es un archivo fijo, ¿por qué lo incluyes una y otra vez en un bucle? Si ese archivo tiene una variable con tu contenido HTML lo lógico es incluirlo una sola vez y usar esa variable en lo adelante, dentro del bucle.

Comment: Pero de que forma podria mostrar lo que hay en el archivo solucion_dpf_egr.php cabe mencionar que estoy haciendo pruebas en primera instancia y lo que eh puesto en ese archivo es un simple <p>Hola mundo</p> @A. Cedano

Comment: A ver. Si el archivo es `.php` tienes que ponerlo en forma de variable, por ejemplo: `$mInclude="<p>Hola mundo</p>";` Y luego en el otro archivo harías el `include('rutaYNombreDeArchivo');` **una sola vez**, y a partir de ahí podrás usar `$mInclude` donde lo necesites. El hecho es que `include()` se usa para poner en contexto lo que hay en otro archivo. Si ese archivo es .php debes usar variables. Si es extensión .html, .css debes usar `file_get_contents()`. Lo que ocurre en tu caso es un error de comprensión sobre `include()` ...

Comment: Y como podria hacerlo sin escrbirlo como variable solamente como estructura html ?, ya que en mi proyecto por ejemplo tengo el header y el footer con extension .php escrito en estructura HTML y hago un include en cada pagina que quiero usarlos y se muestran sin ningun problema @A. Cedano

Comment: Tienes que ponerlo como variable o ponerle `echo` o `print` ... Como ya dije, si el archivo es PHP no sirve poner texto HTML sin más. O puedes ponerlo, pero fuera de las etiquetas de código PHP.

Comment: Lo que quiero es lo siguiente, en el archivo solucion_dpf_egr.php solo poner codigo html sin variables, y luego incluirlo en la funcion que escribi mas arriba, para luego concatenarlo a la variable HTML y retornalo para recuperarlo mediante ajax.

Comment: Amigo si estás usando Ajax lo más simple es lo que te he dicho: guardar el contenido html **en una variable**, poner en contexto ese contenido con include y luego usar la variable para concatenarla al resto del contenido y hacer `echo` del contenido final. Si por ejemplo tu petición Ajax espera un json y no lo haces así el json será invalido porque estarías incluyendo fuera de él contenido html aparte. No entiendo cuál es el problema de no querer usar una variable ¿? ¿Cuál es el motivo por el que quieres complicarte y no usar las prácticas recomendadas para este tipo de casos?